# How to get record from DB using id if no record for that id get increment that id and get record in laravel

Tags: laravel

How to get record from DB using id and if no record for that id,increment that id and get record using incremented id in Laravel
i.e: I`m passing id 50, if no record for id (50),then try for 51 .If not result found for 51 ,then 52...

I tried to increase id like 50 + 1 that's not working for each case.
if there are no id available ,then how to format this code:

i.e

Just i tell you questin clearly
table structure like this

```
id    Personid

50   1
51   2
52   null
53   null
54   null
55   null
56   null
57   5
58   6
```

if i pass id 52 means this will search id 52
there is no value for 52 
then it should search next id 53 thats also null ...
so this should take id 57

Laravel code:

```
public function getApplicantPopupDetails($id, $start = null) {
    $out = [];
    $array = [];
    $out = $this->initOut();
    $PersonId = $id;

    $applicant = DB::table('applicants')
                    ->where('applicants.PersonId', '=', $PersonId)
                    ->get(['Name','Address','Surname','country','Address','ContactNo','Email','created_at','imgUrl']);
    if($applicant->isEmpty()){

        if($start == 0){
            $ids = $PersonId - 1;
        } else {
            $ids = $PersonId + 1;
        }
        $array['main'] = $applicant;
        $this->getApplicantPopupDetails($ids,0);
    }

    $out['results'] = $array;
    return $out;
}
```

I expected the above results without make any problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your code,i understood you want to get row with `PersonId >= $id`,

which can be simply done using below code:

```
public function getApplicantPopupDetails($id, $start = null) {
    $out = [];
    $array = [];
    $out = $this->initOut();
    $PersonId = $id;

     DB::table('applicants')
            ->select('Name','Address','Surname','country','Address','ContactNo','Email','created_at','imgUrl');
            ->where('applicants.PersonId', '>=', $PersonId)
    if($applicant->isEmpty()){

        if($start == 0){
            $ids = $PersonId - 1;
        } else {
            $ids = $PersonId + 1;
        }
        $array['main'] = $applicant;
    }

    $out['results'] = $array;
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this way,

```
public function getApplicantPopupDetails($id, $start = null) {
    $out = [];
    $array = [];
    $out = $this->initOut();
    $PersonId = $id;

    $applicant = DB::table('applicants')
                    ->select('Name','Address','Surname','country','Address','ContactNo','Email','created_at','imgUrl')
                  ->where('applicants.PersonId', '=>', $PersonId)
                   ->first();
   if($applicant->isEmpty()){

       if($start == 0){
           $ids = $PersonId - 1;
       } else {
          $ids = $PersonId + 1;
       }
      $array['main'] = $applicant;
     $this->getApplicantPopupDetails($ids,0);
    }

    $out['results'] = $array;
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function getApplicantPopupDetails($id, $start = null) {
    $out = [];
    $array = [];
    $out = $this->initOut();
    $PersonId = $id;

    $applicant = DB::table('applicants')
                    ->select('Name','Address','Surname','country','Address','ContactNo','Email','created_at','imgUrl')
                  ->where('applicants.PersonId', '=>', $PersonId)
                   ->first();
   if($applicant->isEmpty()){

     $newID = $id+1; //P1
     $newquery = $this->getApplicantPopupDetails($newID,0); //recursive function
      $array['main'] = $applicant;
    }

    $out['results'] = $array;
    return $out;
}
```

P1: just add 1 to given $id and make a recursive call to present function, hope this may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working (Thanks for your support guys)

```
public function getApplicantPopupDetails($id, $start = null) {
    $out = [];
    $array = [];
    $out = $this->initOut();
    $PersonId = $id;

    $applicant = DB::table('applicants')
                    ->where('applicants.PersonId', '=', $PersonId)
                    ->get(['Name','Address','Surname','country','Address','ContactNo','Email','created_at','imgUrl']);
    if($applicant->isEmpty()){

            $applicant = DB::table('applicants')
                    ->where('applicants.PersonId', '>=', $PersonId)
                    ->orderBy('PersonId' ,'ASC')
                    ->first(['PersonId','Name','Address','Surname','country','Address','ContactNo','Email','created_at','imgUrl']);
    }

    $out['results'] = $array;
    return $out;
}
```